# "Windows" tag removed when behavior was Windows-specific

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-edit

I added the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag to [Why doesn't termcolor work for Python 2.7 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858567), but it was subsequently removed by the user who accepted my edit as being irrelevant.  On the contrary, the issue the user is experiencing, and the fix proposed in the answer that the user accepted, are quite platform-specific.  Was their change to my edit reasonable and justified, and if not, what should I do to resolve this?

The other user also replied to my edit in a comment on the question.  As a new user, I am not able to reply to that comment.  How else should I communicate with that user?  Or should I not try to communicate with them to understand their reasoning?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I thought the tags [ansi-colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-colors) and [terminal-color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal-color) were unnecessary because we could use the more relevant tag [termcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/termcolor).

The tag [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) should have been kept. That's why I improved your edit and mentioned Windows in the question title, but I messed up and left out the actual tag.

Sorry about that.

Answer (score 15):

As you've stated, the question and answer clearly debunk the assertion that the platform is irrelevant — indeed, the question *is* platform-specific.

Your only recourse here, since you lack commenting privileges, is to re-submit an edit with the reasoning you have given, as [you have done](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15100612) (and I've approved). This does not guarantee that the user will see the edit, since users aren't notified of edit suggestions on posts they don't own, but unfortunately there is no other way of communicating directly with the user since you don't have a lot of reputation to start with (even participating in chat requires 20).

Hopefully, the other user notices your re-submitted edit notes and understands why the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag is relevant to the question.

Comment: FWIW, the user probably will never see the question again; they appear to have only spotted it in the first place through Improve Edit on the original suggestion.

Comment: They have now [been notified](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35483895#35483895). It was likely just an honest mistake.

Comment: One could argue that it's actually cmd specific issue, just that cmd only runs on Windows

Comment: @Braiam Are you saying that the issue doesn't occur if you start Python on Windows outside of cmd? If so, I suspect you're wrong. Note that cmd is not what's responsible for reading a program's output and rendering it in a window.

Comment: @hvd "To make the ANSI colors used in termcolor work with the **windows terminal**" AFAIK, the only windows terminals are cmd and powershell and the screenshot background/text color combination doesn't looks like powershell's.

Comment: @Braiam It's functionality that's shared across all Windows console applications. cmd happens to be a console application, so it gets it too, but that doesn't make it part of cmd. If you start console applications from Windows Explorer, you'll get the same window, and if you then look at the running processes in Task Manager, you'll notice cmd.exe isn't there.

Comment: @hvd so, how do you call the underlying ui used by console applications?

Comment: @Braiam "Console" or "console window". [Microsoft calls the functions to access that UI "Console Functions".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) And the process responsible for it, conhost.exe, has "Console Window Host" as its descriptive name.

Answer (score -15):

Apparently we have a more relevant tag: [windows-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-console). This tag seems to be used for those questions. Thanks to hvd for the pointer about the topic.

Comment: So in response a question asking why the [windows] tag was removed, and having a diamond moderator as well as the user who removed it both answer it shouldn't have been removed, and both answers getting upvotes, you somehow misconstrue my comments as support for removing the [windows] tag yet again? No, I most certainly did not suggest that. Perhaps the [windows-console] tag could have been added alongside the [windows] tag, but I don't think it's a replacement.

Comment: @hvd well, windows is never on topic for a SO question. Would it?

Comment: "windows is never on topic for a SO question" is not true, and so obviously not true that I suspect you meant something else, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @hvd search for a question were the only valid tag is Windows, or any OS for that matter. We have more specific tags for that very reason. I constantly monitor the debian tag to close general computing questions. The windows tag is the same. Why should we mix both groups of questions?

Comment: Not only did you remove relevant tags, but you also completely butchered the question title. Rolled back.